# Clearing redux state on logout NGRX

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

actions

```
import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const logOut = createAction('[APP] LOGOUT');
```

Reducers

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as LogoutActions from '../actions';

export const clearStateReducer = createReducer(
  on(LogoutActions.logOut, state => {
    return (state = undefined);
  })
);
```

app.module

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers: [clearStateReducer] }),
```

I'm trying to reset the state on clicking the logout button. I did clear the localstorage but I also need to clear redux state. So followed this example `https://medium.com/@moneychaudhary/how-to-reset-the-state-or-clear-the-store-on-logout-in-ngrx-store-d2bd6304f8f3`
But I get error on metareducers, I need somehelp in fixing this.Thank you. I have attached the error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `creatReducer` is not a meta-reducer.

You will have to create something similar as the following:

[image]